VRLA battery cycle use vs standby use choice
I just wonder how to properly maintain VRLA (AGM) battery. It's installed in small RV (Camper van). When RV is in use there are pretty deep discharge overnight and usually solar recharge over day. But when RV is not in use it's parked under the shed and solar panels are in shadow. As I observed how the battery is charged (epever mppt charger) I can't decide how to configure it. In my opinion there is no 'correct' mode.
So to be more specific. I have 200Ah 12V battery. I have 400W solar panel.
On the usual night in RV I use around 50Ah. In the morning when STRONG solar kick on (Over 15A current) the voltage quickly rise to around 14.4V and after around 2 hour current decrease and voltage goes to around 13.8V. The rest of the day the voltage stay at 13.8V and charge current decrease.
That is good day for battery in my opinion. The problem arises when there are isn't strong sun. If got for example just 8A of charge current then in the morning after around 2 hours of charge voltage rises to 14.4V and stay there all the day as battery isn't 100% charged.
Even worse is when RV is parked. If the battery is low I attach grid charger to charge battery, but I remove the charger after battery is charged hours.  Now the battery load is very low at around 100mA. The solar panel even shaded can provide around 1 to 2A. The problem is that every morning after around hour voltage rises to 14.4V and stay there few hours.
I assume that this long time at 14.4V doesn't do any good to battery. I assume that best solution should be to treat battery as standby (13.8V) when RV is not in use, and cycle when is in use. I intend to do such control and write to epever support for that. Sadly they give me response that mode of operation is stored in EEPROM with just 1000 write cycles. So If I do that I will kill the solar charger. What should I do?
p.s.
When battery died the voltages on battery are normal. Just the capacity goes under 1/10 of normal. I assume that this is caused by water decomposition and dry cell. Indeed I try to add water (i use near 1l of distiled water just to fill to top of plates) and after few cycles the battery recover to around 50% capacity.

Why not use a separate, grid-powered, "battery maintainer" when the R.V. is not in use? That way, you won't need to keep reconfiguring your main battery charger back and forth between "charging" mode and "standby" mode. [P.S., How are you able to add water to a VRLA battery?]

RV is parked in area without electricity. When I need to charge it I park at home for that time. To add water I crack the top cover and remove plastic caps. After that caps are put back and cover is glued back.
